# Issue running reading a JSON file then creating a new one in the same LotusScript agent

Tags: json, lotus-domino

I have a Lotusscript agent that calls one subroutine to read a JSON file using the following line:

Set jsnav = session.CreateJSONNavigator(json)

After that subroutine is done, I call another subroutine that creates a new JSON file using the following:

Set jsonNav = session.Createjsonnavigator("")

When this agent is run from a Notes client it works great. When it is set to run as a scheduled agent on the server, I receive this error when 2nd line (above) is called:

Err=4240, error=Problem with input variant

What is causing this and why does it work on the client and not the server?

Comment: How is the agent security set? Is it set to allow restricted operations? Might be a problem with rights within the agent and the error might be misleading...

Comment: The agent security is set to "Allow restricted operations with full administration rights"

Comment: Did you define `Dim jsonNav as NotesJSONNavigator` (or jsnav only)?

Comment: Yes, I am setting both

Comment: I was able to resolve this. The server which the agent was running on was running Domino 10.0.1 FP4. When I ran the agent on a server with 12.0.1 it ran successfully. So there must have been something not in 10.0.1 FP4 that was causing this error. Thanks to all who replied.